# Distribution of sum of binomial variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k$ be random variables with distributions of $Bin(n_1,p_1),Bin(n_2,p_2),\dots,Bin(n_k,p_k)$ respectively.

Let us define $S = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$

We know that if $\ p_i =p_j \ \ \ \forall i,j$,  and that all of the random variables are independent, we get that $S \sim Bin(\sum_{i=1}^k n_i, p)$. (where $p=p_i$ for some $i$)

**My question is this:** Are there any other conditions (weaker?) when we don't demand that the probabilities are equal or that they are independent (maybe we add a different assumption) where we still get $S \sim Bin(m,q)$ for some values $q,m$ and if so what are they, and what are the values $q$ and $m$?

Thanks!

Comment: If they are independent then the characteristic function of $S$ will be $\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-p_i + p_ie^{it})^{n_i}$. Now, to derive pdf one need to use inversion theorem of characteristic functions.

Comment: Thanks. We didn't learn Moment-generating functions yet so I don't understand it yet (I've looked it up online a bit now after you commented here). Is there any other way to show the distribution of $S$ without mgf?